# ASP.NET Textbox not showing up during test run

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

I have this semestral project that i need to complete and i am having problems with my ASP webform.

My asp text box "magically" disappears when i test my application. 
Is there any possible method where i can make sure that my asp text box does not disappear during application testing?

```
  <div class="content-1">
                    <h2>Track by Order Number!</h2>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> 
                        <!-- the label appears in the div tag, but not the textbox-->
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <!-- i want the asp textbox to be in this div -->
                    </p>
                </div>
```

Thank you so very much, i appreciate it alot .

css code:

```
    .content {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    margin: -175px 0 0 120px;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 5;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-radius: 3px;

}

.content div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all linear 0.5s;
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
}

.content div{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-450px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-450px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-450px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-450px);
    transform: translateY(-450px);
}

.tabs input.tab-selector-1:checked ~ .content .content-1,
.tabs input.tab-selector-2:checked ~ .content .content-2,
.tabs input.tab-selector-3:checked ~ .content .content-3,
.tabs input.tab-selector-4:checked ~ .content .content-4 {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -o-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
    z-index: 100;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-out 0.3s 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-out 0.3s 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease-out 0.3s 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease-out 0.3s 0.3s;
    transition: all ease-out 0.3s 0.3s;
}

.content div h2,
.content div h3{
    color: #398080;

}
.content div h2 
{
    font-size: 20px; 
    }
.content div p {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    color: #777;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
    border-left: 8px solid rgba(63,148,148, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What are your problems exactly? Show your work first and tell people what have you tried. People can't read your mind. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing. How about some code and a specific question? We can only make wild guesses as to what you're actually asking and what the problem might be with this little information.

Comment: i am so sorry, i was in the middle of editing the question after i realised it was not specific enough

Comment: Your TextBox "magically disappears"? Are you setting its `Visible` property to `false` somewhere? Does it only happen after you do certain things (e.g. click a button), or is it not showing on page load itself?

Comment: it is not showing up on page load itself

Comment: the visible property is set to true at all times.

Comment: Check the HTML source of the rendered page. Is the textbox there?

Comment: Can you see the label you have in the same div? Is there any code behind of such form? Please show your css class "Content1", most probably the problem is in there.

Comment: Yes i can see the label in the same div. but not the asp textbox. Do i have to add like server side controls?

Comment: Since the textbox is there on the rendered page, it's probably hidden by some css style. Check if you've got any styles that is applying something like `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` on your textbox.

Comment: @FeliceM here is the css code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is some problem either with visibility from server side or display in client side.

To check this remove the css-class from the div. If you see the textbox, you know where to find the problem.

Still if it doesn't show-up then paste the complete cs code, aspx code and css code.

Comment: i can see the textbox after removing the whole css. so do i have to insert a tag in css just for the textbox?

Comment: however, when i tried removing the content part of the css, the textbox doesnt show.

Comment: In this case, _right click->Inspect element_ in any latest browser (Preferably firefox). In the source, go to the textbox (Will be rendered as input of type text) and select it. now you will be able to see the style in right side. Try Unchecking properties like display, margin, position, Bottom, Left, Right, Top, etc... Eventually you will find the property which is **Magically Disappearing** your textbox

Comment: thank you! that helped me to identify where the css-code that was causing the problem and i removed it. thank you! it works perfectly now